# Flutter store List of custom Classes in Shared Preferences

Tags: json, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, encode

I have List of custom objects which also have fields with non-primitive datatypes. I would like to store a `list` of these objects in `SharedPreferences`. This is my `List` and also the simple `Data`:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class MedicamentsBase {
  final List<Medicament> data;

  const MedicamentsBase({
    required this.data,
  });

  factory MedicamentsBase.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$MedicamentsBaseFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MedicamentsBaseToJson(this);
}



@JsonSerializable()
class Medicament {
  @JsonKey(name: '_id')
  String id;
  String name;
  int dosageAmount;
  String dosageType;
  DateTime startDate;
  DateTime endDate;
  List<DateTime> timesOfDay;
  String intakeContext;
  bool notify;
  int notificationId;

  Medicament({
    required this.name,
    required this.dosageAmount,
    required this.dosageType,
    required this.startDate,
    required this.endDate,
    required this.timesOfDay,
    required this.intakeContext,
    required this.notify,
    required this.notificationId,
    required this.id,
  });

  factory Medicament.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$MedicamentFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MedicamentToJson(this);

}
```

I already serialized them. But if I try to store the `MedicamentsBase` like this:

```
   static Future<void> setMedicaments(List<Medicament> medicaments) async {
    final SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences =
        await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    await _sharedPreferences.setStringList(
      'key',
      medicaments.map((medicament) => json.encode(medicament)).toList(),
    );
  }
```

Things are not working as expected if trying to get the List back like this:

```
   static Future<List<Medicament>> getMedicaments() async {
    final SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences =
        await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    return MedicamentsBase.fromJson(
      _sharedPreferences.getStringList('key') as Map<String, dynamic>,
    ).data;
  }
```

I think it is because `Medicament` also has `Strings` and `DateTimes` in it. What is the correct way to store and get this kind of data in `Shared Preferences`?

Comment: Is there a "Must" to use SharedPreferences? because you can use hive which handles this situation easily.

Comment: @Xoltawn not an absolute must but definitely preferred. Ive read about Hive but implementing it would be more effort I think and time/money rare in this case :D

Comment: In my opinion it's worth it. if you dive into it, you would see it's not as scary as it looks at first sight. But I haven't done this scenario in SharedPreferences so I have no opinion about that.

Comment: I will have a look at it, as it looks quite promising. However for now I will stick to SF. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: How about encoding the list as a single string instead of encoding item of the list as list of string?

Comment: how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences might not be the way to go if you are intending on saving more complex data types, I think your options are:

- Checking out on how to use the [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) package
- Trying to save primitive type which you can later use to reconstruct your complex data types with using shared preferences
- Create a ToJson / FromJson functions in your complex data types, and use the file.dart function which are available as part of flutter to save this data as a json file, take alook at those functions which should be useful to do so:

write the file:

```
    Directory applicationDocumentDirectory =
        await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    File file = Directory applicationDocumentDirectory =
        await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    Map<String, dynamic> fileJson = yourDataType.toJson();
    String dataAsJsonString = jsonEncode(fileJson);
    songDataFile.writeAsStringSync(dataAsJsonString);


    String fileData = file.readAsStringSync();

    return jsonDecode(fileData);
```

read the file:

```
    Directory applicationDocumentDirectory =
        await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    File file = Directory applicationDocumentDirectory =
        await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    String fileData = file.readAsStringSync();

    return jsonDecode(fileData);
```

Hopefully those ideas help :)